# Pattern matching with special character "-" hyphen isn't working as expected .?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

```
Pattern.matches(".*[!@#$%^&*()-+].*","AUzs-nV");
```

Is returning false.  Even though string pattern matching sequence contains "-" hyphen.

Comment: escape it with `\\\`

Comment: In a character class (delimited by `[]`), the hyphen needs to be escaped unless it is the first character in the class. Also, your initial wildcard quantifier should be reluctant instead of greedy (use `.*?` instead of `.*`).